# Determining whether different groups of users click on certain URLs more frequently?

Tags: clustering, similarities

Let's say I have a stream of click data that looks like this:

```
USER-ID,SHIRT-COLOR,URL
1,blue,http://a.com/apple.html
2,black,http://a.com/banana.html
2,black,http://a.com/apple.html
1,blue,http://a.com/cherry.html
3,red,http://a.com/cherry.html
4,blue,http://a.com/apple.html
4,blue,http://a.com/cherry.html
5,red,http://a.com/banana.html
```

I'm trying to figure out whether shirt color is a predictor of clicks. So, are certain URLs are more "popular" amongst people with a red shirts than amongst the general population? Or another way to say it: Is someone with a red shirt more likely to click on a URL that is popular amongst red shirts?

The number of URLs and User-IDs are in the thousands, but the short-colors are just a handfull.

I'm hoping someone could help me determine what type of problem this is (Clustering? Fuzzy clustering? Chi-squared?) and any tips on solving it.